# Facebook Feed (RSS using PHP)

Tags: php, rss

Can someone tell me what happens when i enter a link into the Facebook Status Update Form and it loads up a mini info kinda thing of the website (I'm guessing its RSS or something?)
How do i implement this on my site using PHP?

What do i need to learn to be able to implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It scrapes the page you are linking to. It doesn't have anything to do with RSS.

By looking at the HTML of the page it can get the page title for you and find all the images that can be used as a thumbnail.

Take a look at [HTTP](http://php.net/http) or [cURL](http://php.net/curl) in the PHP manual for methods to get webpage content.